# How to cast object type to a specific sobject in apex?

Tags: apex, typecast

I have json string when deserialized looks like this  -

> {a038W0000*********={Checkbox_Response__c=true, RecordId=a038W0000*********}, a038W0000*********={RecordId=a038W0000*********, Response__c=345}}

This is a Map<String,Object> when deserialized.

I am unable to retrieve the values in the sobject type i.e

```apex
Map<String,Object> result 
    = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(strJSONData);
List<Object> mapValues = result.values();
```

I am unable to retrieve each value from the generic object list and map it to a sObj field.

I have been unsuccessful with -

1. List<Custom_Object__c> customobjects.addAll(mapValues);
2. Casting to string -> String temp = (String) eachMapValue.Response__c;

Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Swat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making extra work for yourself by passing in the data this way. Instead, on the JavaScript side, arrange your data like this:

```
[ 
  { sobjectType: 'Custom_Object__c', Id: 'a038...', Checkbox_Response__c: true }, 
  { sobjectType: 'Custom_Object__c', Id: 'a038...', Response__c: 345} 
]
```

Then, on the Apex side, it's as simple as:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void method(Custom_Object__c[] records) {
  // ...
```

This means zero JSON manipulation on Apex, making it faster and more efficient.

However, if you really, absolutely insist on doing it the long way around, you can. The `Object` inside each value for the Map is actually a `Map<String, Object>` as well.

```
Custom_Object__[] records = new Custom_Object__c[0];
for(Object param: params.values()) {
  Map<String, Object> recordData = (Map<String, Object>)param;
  Custom_Object__c record = new Custom_Object__c();
  for(String field: recordData.keySet()) {
    record.put(field, recordData.get(field));
  }
  records.add(record);
}
update records;
```

Seriously, though, you should definitely consider making your data easier to upload, let the framework help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding.My lwc has a record-edit-form within a template:for.  Each row is a question record within which a response is captured. In order to map responses in each row to the right question i used that format. I am using a onchange handler,it captures every character change on the response and records it as an entry (instead of just the complete response) when i tried to create json in the format you suggested.Ex- if i typed 'cat' as my first response . json would look like {Id: 'a038...', Response__c: c},{Id: 'a038...', Response__c: ca},{Id: 'a038...', Response__c: cat}

Comment: @swat That's a problem with your logic client-side. You can use the Map/Object that you're using to build the values, but when you go to save the data, then you use `Object.values(this.dataRows)` to get a clean Array of updates to send to the server.